# Changing the form after log in in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a login and registration form in python using Tkinter. I have this problem I want to open a new form name game after the login is successful but I do not know how to make that happen and what should I change in my code.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox
import sqlite3

root = Tk()
root.title("Python: Simple Inventory System")
 
width = 640
height = 480
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
root.resizable(0, 0)


#=======================================VARIABLES=====================================
USERNAME = StringVar()
PASSWORD = StringVar()
FIRSTNAME = StringVar()
LASTNAME = StringVar()

#=======================================METHODS=======================================
def Database():
    global conn, cursor
    conn = sqlite3.connect("db_member.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (mem_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, username TEXT, password TEXT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT)")


def Exit():
    result = tkMessageBox.askquestion('System', 'Are you sure you want to exit?', icon="warning")
    if result == 'yes':
        root.destroy()
        exit()


def LoginForm():
    global LoginFrame, lbl_result1
    LoginFrame = Frame(root)
    LoginFrame.pack(side=TOP, pady=80)
    lbl_username = Label(LoginFrame, text="Username:", font=('arial', 25), bd=18)
    lbl_username.grid(row=1)
    lbl_password = Label(LoginFrame, text="Password:", font=('arial', 25), bd=18)
    lbl_password.grid(row=2)
    lbl_result1 = Label(LoginFrame, text="", font=('arial', 18))
    lbl_result1.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
    username = Entry(LoginFrame, font=('arial', 20), textvariable=USERNAME, width=15)
    username.grid(row=1, column=1)
    password = Entry(LoginFrame, font=('arial', 20), textvariable=PASSWORD, width=15, show="*")
    password.grid(row=2, column=1)
    btn_login = Button(LoginFrame, text="Login", font=('arial', 18), width=35, command=Login)
    btn_login.grid(row=4, columnspan=2, pady=20)
    lbl_register = Label(LoginFrame, text="Register", fg="Blue", font=('arial', 12))
    lbl_register.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    lbl_register.bind('<Button-1>', ToggleToRegister)

def RegisterForm():
    global RegisterFrame, lbl_result2
    RegisterFrame = Frame(root)
    RegisterFrame.pack(side=TOP, pady=40)
    lbl_username = Label(RegisterFrame, text="Username:", font=('arial', 18), bd=18)
    lbl_username.grid(row=1)
    lbl_password = Label(RegisterFrame, text="Password:", font=('arial', 18), bd=18)
    lbl_password.grid(row=2)
    lbl_firstname = Label(RegisterFrame, text="Firstname:", font=('arial', 18), bd=18)
    lbl_firstname.grid(row=3)
    lbl_lastname = Label(RegisterFrame, text="Lastname:", font=('arial', 18), bd=18)
    lbl_lastname.grid(row=4)
    lbl_result2 = Label(RegisterFrame, text="", font=('arial', 18))
    lbl_result2.grid(row=5, columnspan=2)
    username = Entry(RegisterFrame, font=('arial', 20), textvariable=USERNAME, width=15)
    username.grid(row=1, column=1)
    password = Entry(RegisterFrame, font=('arial', 20), textvariable=PASSWORD, width=15, show="*")
    password.grid(row=2, column=1)
    firstname = Entry(RegisterFrame, font=('arial', 20), textvariable=FIRSTNAME, width=15)
    firstname.grid(row=3, column=1)
    lastname = Entry(RegisterFrame, font=('arial', 20), textvariable=LASTNAME, width=15)
    lastname.grid(row=4, column=1)
    btn_login = Button(RegisterFrame, text="Register", font=('arial', 18), width=35, command=Register)
    btn_login.grid(row=6, columnspan=2, pady=20)
    lbl_login = Label(RegisterFrame, text="Login", fg="Blue", font=('arial', 12))
    lbl_login.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    lbl_login.bind('<Button-1>', ToggleToLogin)

def ToggleToLogin(event=None):
    RegisterFrame.destroy()
    LoginForm()

def ToggleToRegister(event=None):
    LoginFrame.destroy()
    RegisterForm()

def Register():
    Database()
    if USERNAME.get == "" or PASSWORD.get() == "" or FIRSTNAME.get() == "" or LASTNAME.get == "":
        lbl_result2.config(text="Please complete the required field!", fg="orange")
    else:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `username` = ?", (USERNAME.get(),))
        if cursor.fetchone() is not None:
            lbl_result2.config(text="Username is already taken", fg="red")
        else:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `member` (username, password, firstname, lastname) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", (str(USERNAME.get()), str(PASSWORD.get()), str(FIRSTNAME.get()), str(LASTNAME.get())))
            conn.commit()
            USERNAME.set("")
            PASSWORD.set("")
            FIRSTNAME.set("")
            LASTNAME.set("")
            lbl_result2.config(text="Successfully Created!", fg="black")
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
def Login():
    Database()
    if USERNAME.get == "" or PASSWORD.get() == "":
        lbl_result1.config(text="Please complete the required field!", fg="orange")
    else:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `username` = ? and `password` = ?", (USERNAME.get(), PASSWORD.get()))
        if cursor.fetchone() is not None:
            lbl_result1.config(text="You Successfully Login", fg="blue")
        else:
            lbl_result1.config(text="Invalid Username or password", fg="red")
LoginForm()

#========================================MENUBAR WIDGETS==================================
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=Exit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)


#========================================INITIALIZATION===================================
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

I want to open a new form with a new button after the login (after this message `"You Successfully Login"`).

Comment: Your question is way too vague. How is a login's success determined? How would a "new form name game" be displayed? How are older/previous ones being displayed?

Comment: You seem to have your answer right in your code. See the ToggleToRegister() function, this seems to do the job. Just insert it your "if cursor.fetchone() is not None: etc."

Comment: @tgrandje what should i write after is not none??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken your functions LoginForm and RegisterForm both give you an example to create a new form.

Your functions ToggleToLogin and ToggleToRegister both allow you to navigate between those forms.

So you seem to have everything in this code (except maybe the new form you want to create).

For example, try this :

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `username` = ? and `password` = ?", (USERNAME.get(), PASSWORD.get()))
  if cursor.fetchone() is not None:
    lbl_result1.config(text="You Successfully Login", fg="blue")
    ToggleToRegister()
```

Note that I'm not used to tkinter and that I didn't try your code ; I'm just adding this as a followup of my previous comment (as comments don't allow formatted code). This answer is a untried guess after a look at your code. Nothing more...